# How does UnicodeDecodeError exception work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

If I take a file with not valid utf-8 charakters (I saved this page as file.txt: https://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/UTF-8-demo.html) and try to check whether each line in this file contains valid utf8 (if not, this line should be ignored) I get the error message:

> File "test.py", line 13, in                                                                                       for line in file:                                                                                                    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]                                                   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 240: character maps to undefined

The code:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    try:
        print(line)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print("UnicodeDecodeError " + line)
        pass
```

Should the except-line & pass not ensure that if a UnicodeDecodeError occurs, it will be ignored and the script continues with the next line ?

Comment: It would if the exception were actually coming from `print(line)`, but the stack trace pretty clearly shows it's not.

Comment: Also, use code formatting for error messages. Don't use quote formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is raised while a line is being read, which happens in the `for` iterator. You need to encapsulate the line reading into an exception handling block, for which you need a bit more manual handling than the implicit iterator provided by `for`:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    while True:
        try:
            line = fh.readline()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print('error')  # line is obviously not available to output here, since it failed to decode
            continue

        if not line:
            break  # end the loop when the file is at its end

        print(line)
```

Note that I'm not sure how this actually behaves with a broken file, whether it's even possible to continue reading after having encountered broken bytes. If this doesn't work, you'll need to do it even more manually and open the file in `'rb'` mode to get raw `bytes`, which you then manually try to `.decode('utf-8')`. This approach would also allow you to output the line which failed to decode as raw bytes, which is by definition not possible when reading the file as text.